# Generate jquery contextmenu item depending on php session variable?

Tags: jquery

I have [this](https://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/demo.html) jQuery `context-menu` and I need to generate certain menu item, depending on `PHP $_SESSION` variable. For example, if I'm a normal user, I'll just see "**new**" and "**edit**" options. But if I'm an admin user, I'll see the "**Delete user**" option too.

Something like this:

```
$(function() {
  $.contextMenu({
    selector: '.context-menu-one',
    autoHide: true,
    callback: function(key, options) {
      if(key=="Edit") myFunction1(this);
      if(key=="New") myFunction2(this);
      if(key=="Del") myFunction3(this);
    },
    items: {
      "New": {name: "New", icon: "fa-plus-circle"},
      "Edit": {name: "Edit",icon: "fa-pencil-square-o"},
      var grade = <?php echo $_SESSION["grade"];?>;     //this doesn't work
      if(grade == "admin"){                             //but this is what I
        "Del": {name: "Delete user", icon: "fa-trash"}, //want
      }
      "sep1": "---------",
      "quit": {name: "Close", icon: function(){
          return 'context-menu-icon context-menu-icon-quit';
        }
      }
    },
  });    
});
```

Any ideas on how to do it?

## Edit:

The php `$_SESSION["grade"]` is ok, it returns the value, so I have no problem with that.

Comment: have you echo'd `$_SESSION["grade"]` before use in jQuery ? if you know it returns a value, then, try and assign it like `var grade = '<?php echo"$my_admin_grade";?>';` (as per the DOC: `Strings are written inside double or single quotes.`) and then check console to see if 'grade' is set. Any better ?

Comment: yes, it returns the value. That's not the problem @OldPadawan, the problem is that the commented lines aren't the right way to do what I want. That's why I'm asking how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have a statement in the middle of your dictionary (in particular the variable assignment and the if statement). You need to extract it similarly to this

```
$(function() {
  var options = {
    selector: '.context-menu-one',
    autoHide: true,
    callback: function(key, options) {
      if(key=="Edit") myFunction1(this);
      if(key=="New") myFunction2(this);
      if(key=="Del") myFunction3(this);
    },
    items: {
      "New": {name: "New", icon: "fa-plus-circle"},
      "Edit": {name: "Edit",icon: "fa-pencil-square-o"},
      "sep1": "---------",
      "quit": {name: "Close", icon: function(){
          return 'context-menu-icon context-menu-icon-quit';
        }
      }
    },
  }
  var grade = <?php echo $_SESSION["grade"];?>;     
  if(grade == "admin"){                            
    options.items["Del"] = {name: "Delete user", icon: "fa-trash"}, 
  }
  $.contextMenu(options);    
});)
```